# Emulate git cp, including files with spaces in names

Tags: git, cygwin, whitespace, cp

Yes I know that that what I want (git cp a b) approximately equal to

```
cp -R a b
git add b
```

However this adds files that aren't in the repository.  The closest I have gotten is

```
cd a
git ls-files > ../files.txt
cd ../b
cat ../files.txt | xargs git add
```

almost works, but there are problems with files with whitespace in the name.  I'm using Cygwin for what it's worth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the file list by a character that cannot occur in file names, i.e., the null character. Try:

```
(cd a && git ls-files -z) | (cd b && xargs -0 git add)
```

Comment: Then probably commit and remove the untracked files would do it.

Comment: This code might break if the `cd b` fails. Then there is nobody reading at the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

0Combining my try and @Philipp's answer

```
cp -R a b
cd a
git ls-files -z > ../files.txt
cd ../b
cat ../files.txt | xargs -0 git add
```

Comment: `xargs -0` not `xargs -o`, and you can avoid the cat with the `-a` option.